# PDFLib.NET dll for .NET Framework4.0?

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, pdflib

I have developed a searchable PDF viewer in .NET2.0. We are now upgrading our application to 4.0 so that PDFLibNet.dll is compatible with this version.

The message is:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'PDFLibNet, Version=1.0.6.8, Culture=neutral, 
PublicKeyToken=26d87f7d66fb2aee' or one of its dependencies. 
Strong name signature could not be verified.  The assembly may have been tampered with, or 
it was delay signed but not fully signed with the correct private key. (Exception from     HRESULT: 0x80131045)
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PDFLib.NET dll does not support to 4.0 but compatible with 3.5!

But the below link explains that how to take a build to 4.0 it fails. works only with 3.5

http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DesktopDev/MSTech/use-pdfviewernet-in-a-project

Answer (score 2):

In case if someone else is having the same problem, the .NET 4 version of the assembly and the public/private key file can be downloaded from

http://code.google.com/p/pdfviewernet/source/browse/trunk/PDFView/?r=78#PDFView%2FPDFLibNet

Using the key file it is easy to resign the assembly using

`sn -R PDFLibNet.dll PDFLibNet.snk`

It should work after that.

Comment: This solved my issue on my build machine with this error: SGEN: Could not load file or assembly 'PDFLibNet, Version=1.0.6.8, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=26d87f7d66fb2aee' or one of its dependencies. Strong name validation failed. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8013141A)